# Can I use Proc::Reliable on windows?

Tags: windows, perl, activeperl

I'm using ActivePerl on a Win 7 box and I want to use the Proc::Reliable CPAN module.  It downloaded and installed properly but when I tried to run the following code, it failed at `run`

```
my $newProc = Proc::Reliable->new()
$newProc->run("perl.exe -e print 'hello world'");
```

I tried a couple things, such as testing the `status` and trying to retrieve output, but with no luck.  As best as I can tell, the program dies silently on `run`.

For reference perl.exe is in my `PATH` variable and I'm calling this from commandline as: `perl.exe test.pl`

Comment: what happens if you do `dir` as your command instead of perl.exe?

Comment: @DVK nothing. Program terminates without output

Comment: nm, I fixed it, ysth was right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably isn't failing.  `-e print 'hello world'` tells perl to execute the code `print` with @ARGV set to `hello world` (or perhaps `("'hello","world'")`, I forgot how windows cmd quoting handles '').  This prints the contents of $_ (that is, undef) to STDOUT.

Always use warnings.  Even on one-liners.  Perhaps especially on one-liners.  Compare:

```
$ perl -e print 'hello world'
$
```

and

```
$ perl -we print 'hello world'
Use of uninitialized value $_ in print at -e line 1.
$
```

Comment: If I believed my program was failing for other reasons, what would be the correct way to test it? I used -e print, because it was quick, is there any other way?

Comment: @tzenes: sorry, I don't actually know anything about Proc::Reliable.  It seems like it should provide some well documented way to test, though. Change the inner program to create a file or output a debugging statement to see if it's starting at all?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting is a little different in the Windows "shell". To get your mini-program to be interpreted as a single argument, try something like

```
perl.exe -e "print qq/hello world/"
```

Comment: While that does work for windows "shell" it won't display any output in my example as the stdout isn't redirect to the "shell" (or anywhere else).

Comment: @tzenes: What if you say `($stdout) = $newProc->run('perl.exe -e ...'); print $stdout` ? It looks like the output of the process should be captured by the `Proc::Reliable` module and returned.

Comment: I get no output or the print $stdout fails.  Upon further investigation, any `print` after a `run` fails.

Answer (score 2):

I have contacted the author of the `Proc::Reliable` module and he confirmed that the module does not work on Windows.